# how can i send every single fetched data from mysql into another page

Tags: php

i have 2 pages "customize.php" and "deepview.php"
**this is customiz.php:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<?php
session_start();
?>
<style>
.site {
/* width: 100%; */
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
text-align: center;
padding: 25px;
}

.site:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
</style>

<div id="vcs"> <!-- view of customize site -->

<?php
include ('connection.php');

$sql = "SELECT site_name FROM sites";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<a href='#' id='custlink' data-target='deepview'><div class='col-sm-4 site'>";
        echo $row['site_name'];
        echo "</div></a>";
        $_SESSION['session_site_name'] = $row['site_name'];   
    }
}

?>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// custlink is the id of the link
$("a, #custlink").on("click", function() {
     var target = $(this).data('target');
     $("#vcs").load(target + '.php');
     return true;
})
})
</script>
```

**this is deepview.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<style>
.deepsite {
/* width: 100%; */
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
text-align: center;
padding: 25px;
}

.deepsite:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

</style>

<?php
include ('connection.php');

$clicked_site_name = $_SESSION['session_site_name'];

$sql = "SELECT date from  tables WHERE site_name='".$clicked_site_name."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<a href='#'><div class='col-sm-4 deepsite'>";
        echo $row['date'];
        echo "</div></a>";
    }
}
?>
```

here what i want is when i click a link on customize.php to load deepview.php and select "date" from mysql table where its "site_name" is the site i clicked in customize.php

i tried the above code, it successfully load deepview.php, but it always loads the same "date", even though i clicked different "sites" in customize.php.

[this is table "tables"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FQsT.png)

[this is table "sites" from mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myO6A.png)

[this is customize.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrvRK.png)

[this is deepview.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg1Lu.png)

Comment: What you are currently trying to do there with the session does not make sense, because you are _overwriting_ that session value in each loop iteration. You should pass the necessary site identifier along as a URL parameter.

Comment: And btw., IDs _must_ be unique in HTML, so you should not have `id='custlink'` inside of a loop in the first place.

Comment: hey there, i solved the problem. yeah the session does not make sense, instead i use the global variable $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

in customize.php i changed the previous code with

```
$sql = "SELECT site_name FROM sites";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rr = $row['site_name'];

?>

<a href='#' data-target="database/deepview.php?lo=<?php echo "$rr"; ?>">

<?php    
    echo "<div class='col-sm-4 site'>";
    echo $rr;
    echo "</div></a>";
}
}
```

and i mentioned the "lo" using the global variable $_GET in deepview.php

```
$sql = "SELECT date from  tables WHERE site_name='".$_GET['lo']."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rr = $row['date'];
?>

<a href='' id='sslink' data-target='database/viewsinglesite?lo=<?php echo "$rr"; ?>'>

<?php

    echo "<div class='col-sm-4 deepsite'>";
    echo $row['date'];
    echo "</div></a>";
}
}
```